# WPF error "Window must be the root of the tree. Cannot add Window as a child of Visual" in Prism dialog service UI using MetroWindow

Tags: wpf, prism

I'm encountering an issue in my WPF application where it crashes with the error "Window must be the root of the tree. Cannot add Window as a child of Visual" when using MetroWindow in Prism dialog service UI. I'm using Prism for WPF with MahApps.Metro for styling.

**Description:**
I'm using the Prism dialog service (IDialogService) to display dialogs in my application, and I've encountered a problem where the application crashes with the mentioned error.

I have a dialog view (DialogView.xaml) that uses MahApps.Metro's MetroWindow as the root. I used the IDialogService.ShowDialog method to show the dialog.

Code:

```
<mah:MetroWindow x:Class="YourNamespace.YourDialogView"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                 Title="Your Dialog Title"
                 Height="300" Width="400">
    <!-- Your dialog content goes here -->
</mah:MetroWindow>
```

Exception Details:
The application crashes with the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Window must be the root of the tree. Cannot add Window as a child of Visual.
```

- Has anyone encountered a similar issue with Prism dialog service, MahApps.Metro, and the mentioned error?
- Are there any specific considerations or configurations needed when using MetroWindow in Prism dialog service UI?

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The dialog view gets embedded in a dialog window provided by prism (customizable, of course) - it is not a window itself.